# Can the "Add to my calendar"-link in an event in Sharepoint Online be removed?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, events

as the question says - can the "Add to my calendar"-link in an event in Sharepoint Online be removed or altered? I can't seem to find out where...

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I'm afraid we can't remove this "Add to my calendar" link, it's designed by SharePoint and we can't change it.